# Qt iOS Android Wlan or Bluetooth

Tags: android, ios, qt, wifi

I have to develop an App which run on Android and iOS (iPhone). These devices should communicate with other devices (Windows, Linux, iOS, Android). Is Bluetooth communication and/or Wlan Ad Hoc possible with Qt and Android /iOS?

Thx.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question as it is could not fit well on Stack Overflow. You should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). An often made comment to your question could be: did you googled "Bluetooth Qt" and did you click on the first hit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Communication is quite easy realized ove WLan using QNetwork*. Bluetooth can become quite challenging. Almost all devices support WLan while some Tablets and similar devices do not support Bluetooth (especially the cheaper ones). Also the complexity of code is much easier using standard networking ?(WLan) function.

Comment: Are there any examples for QNetwork and WLan & AdHoc?

Comment: Since your WLan and AdHoc is actually configured outside of your application using the Android-Settings an example probably does not exist, at least i did not see any yet (not trying to find an example). Accessing the currently connected networks is quite easy using the qnetworkmanager

Answer (score 0):

Support for Android and iOS still "tech preview" in Qt 5.1, but network should be available. In the worst cases, you can use NDK until having Qt full support

For bluetooth support, this is in dev (http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-dev/qtbluetooth-index.html), maybe available in Qt 5.2. You can test it or use directly NDK

No simple solution actually...